# RequestFactory slow on Android

Tags: java, android, requestfactory

I am using RequestFactory with appengine and android.  It has been working great, however when I retrieve a list of objects of any size(around 400) it has a very delayed response.  It appears that the transfer of data happens fairly quickly(~4 secs), however I do not get the onSuccess() callback until much later(1-2 mins or greater).  I am guessing this could be slow performance of parsing within requestfactory.  My objects are just POJOs with about 10 fields of text and longs.

My question is has anyone come across this? Anyone have a more efficient way to get lots of data off of appengine quickly in android?

UPDATE:  I also have ran into outofmemoryerrors when using RF with lots of entities(3000+).  I switched to straight json using the GSON lib and parsing was quicker and have not ran into memory problems yet.

The specific Entity I am sending over the wire is below(I am using Objectify).

```
@Cached
@Entity
public class InterestPoint
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private Long groupId;
private String more, data;
@Unindexed
private int lat, longi;
@Unindexed
private String address, city, state;
@Unindexed
private int num1, num2, num3;
@Unindexed
private int num4,num5,num6;
@Unindexed
private String name;
@Unindexed
private int moreData;
@Unindexed
private String notes;
}
```

Comment: What type of object is it. In other words we need to setup a test case for this. Did it have children objects? Can you provide the objects source, maybe with renamed parameters?

Comment: @Branflake2267 added the source of the entities(with names changed).  Nothing fancy here just ints, strings, and longs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to the author's description of the problem

We're retrieving 8 relatively small objects and each has one to four child objects which are tiny:

Here's an example of the stack after the response has been returned from the server, for over a minute it's in the org.json package or com.google.web.bindery and we have high cpu usage:

```
java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder append0 AbstractStringBuilder.java  143 false   
java.lang.StringBuilder append  StringBuilder.java  125 false   
org.json.JSONStringer   string  JSONStringer.java   344 false   
org.json.JSONStringer   value   JSONStringer.java   252 false   
org.json.JSONObject quote   JSONObject.java 713 false   
com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.StringQuoter    quote   StringQuoter.java   69  false   
com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.StringQuoter    create  StringQuoter.java   50  false   
com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.ValueCodex$Type$13   encode  ValueCodex.java 193 false   
com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.ValueCodex   encode  ValueCodex.java 315 false   
com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AutoBeanCodexImpl$ValueCoder    extractSplittable   AutoBeanCodexImpl.java  500 false   
com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean    setProperty AbstractAutoBean.java   277 false   
com.google.web.bindery.autobean.vm.impl.ProxyAutoBean   setProperty ProxyAutoBean.java  253 false   
com.google.web.bindery.autobean.vm.impl.BeanPropertyContext set BeanPropertyContext.java    44  false   
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$3  visitValueProperty  AbstractRequestContext.java 910 false   
com.google.web.bindery.autobean.vm.impl.ProxyAutoBean   traverseProperties  ProxyAutoBean.java  289 false   
com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean    traverse    AbstractAutoBean.java   166 false   
com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AbstractAutoBean    accept  AbstractAutoBean.java   101 false   
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext    processReturnOperation  AbstractRequestContext.java 879 false   
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext    processReturnOperations AbstractRequestContext.java 1215    false   
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext    access$600  AbstractRequestContext.java 76  false   
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$StandardPayloadDialect processPayload  AbstractRequestContext.java 347 false   
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$5  onTransportSuccess  AbstractRequestContext.java 1108    false   
com.whichfestival.AndroidRequestTransport   send    AndroidRequestTransport.java    68  false   
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext    doFire  AbstractRequestContext.java 1102    false   
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext    fire    AbstractRequestContext.java 569 false   
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequest   fire    AbstractRequest.java    54  false   
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequest   fire    AbstractRequest.java    59  false   
com.whichfestival.FetchTopService   getEvents   FetchTopService.java    99  false   
com.whichfestival.FetchTopService   onHandleIntent  FetchTopService.java    56  false   
android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler    handleMessage   IntentService.java  59  false   
android.os.Handler  dispatchMessage Handler.java    99  false   
android.os.Looper   loop    Looper.java 130 false   
android.os.HandlerThread    run HandlerThread.java  60  false
```

And we see the GC kick in about 25 times:

```
11-16 22:30:28.464: D/dalvikvm(416): GC_CONCURRENT freed 930K, 51% free 3321K/6727K, external 1654K/2137K, paused 15ms+10ms

11-16 22:30:33.605: D/dalvikvm(416): GC_CONCURRENT freed 515K, 49% free 3452K/6727K, external 1654K/2137K, paused 10ms+13ms

11-16 22:30:37.554: D/dalvikvm(416): GC_CONCURRENT freed 638K, 49% free 3497K/6727K, external 1654K/2137K, paused 11ms+10ms

11-16 22:30:43.424: D/dalvikvm(416): GC_CONCURRENT freed 681K, 47% free 3572K/6727K, external 1654K/2137K, paused 6ms+9ms
```

all for about 15 small pojos... would appreciate any help. Absolutely desperate to solve this.

Comment: Shermus,  that is what I expected but never got that deep into it.  Thanks for the post.  This is a big problem when I retrieve a large number of objects.  I'm considering other approaches that do not use the requestfactory.  Unfortunate because it is so nice to have the same code on android and appengine!

Comment: Update:  For my purposes I am not using RF for transfer of large number of entities.  I have made an implementation using CSV and a custom servlet and http request.  It was fairly easy in my case because I am dealing with simple objects.  The results were MUCH faster(10x-20x faster!).

Comment: The same here, but also on standard web-browser application. While request is truly asynchronous, all the operations between request transport callback and my receiver takes up a long time and freezes the entire view. From my research, the problem lies somewhere in AbstractRequestContext#processReturnOperations (the same as Sheamus noticed). Maybe you have any other suggestions than switching from request factory completely? :)

Comment: Was this resolved? Did it have to do with this? http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7231